# How to catch Masonry end?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

In my project i'm using Masonry plugin to organize my blocks. So i wondering is there any event which fires after Masonry completes it's task? I already tried this code, which didn't do anything except reordering my blocks as they should be...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    // also tried in jQuery style
    var msnry = new Masonry(document.getElementById('timeline'), {itemSelector : 'article'});
    // doesn't fire
    msnry.on( 'layoutComplete', function( msnryInstance, laidOutItems ){
        console.log('layout done, just this one time');
        return true;
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `layout` event finished before you even had the event bound to a completion handler. You could just call the `.layout()` method again, which would trigger the method.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    // also tried in jQuery style
    var msnry = new Masonry(document.getElementById('timeline'), {itemSelector : 'article'});
    // doesn't fire
    msnry.on( 'layoutComplete', function( msnryInstance, laidOutItems ){
        console.log('layout done, just this one time');
        return true;
    });

    // Triggers the onLayoutComplete.
    msnry.layout();
})
```